# Local Npm module "grunt-parallel" not found. Is it installed?

Tags: gruntjs, npm

After update to node5 and npm3 I got such kind of warning for running grunt:

```
Local Npm module "grunt-parallel" not found. Is it installed?
```

I don't use `grunt-parallel` and would like to know the reason why this warning appeared.

Set of modules that we are using in our project:

```js
var modules = {
         "MD5": "~1.2.1",
        "bower": "~1.4.1",
        "chai": "~1.9.1",
        "colors": "~0.6.2",
        "express": "~3.4.8",
        "grunt": "~0.4.5",
        "grunt-cli": "~0.1.13",
        "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
        "grunt-contrib-compass": "~0.7.2",
        "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
        "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.5.0",
        "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.10.0",
        "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.10.0",
        "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.5.0",
        "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",
        "grunt-express": "~1.2.1",
        "grunt-grunticon": "^1.2.3",
        "grunt-html2js": "~0.2.4",
        "grunt-jslinker": "~0.1.5",
        "grunt-json": "^0.1.3",
        "grunt-karma": "~0.8.3",
        "grunt-ng-annotate": "~0.2.3",
        "grunt-open": "~0.2.3",
        "grunt-protractor-runner": "~1.1.4",
        "grunt-replace": "~0.7.8",
        "karma": "~0.12.17",
        "karma-chai": "~0.1.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1.4",
        "karma-coverage": "~0.2.4",
        "karma-mocha": "~0.1.6",
        "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.1.4",
        "karma-sinon": "~1.0.3",
        "load-grunt-tasks": "~0.6.0",
        "method-override": "^2.0.2",
        "mocha": "~1.20.1",
        "protractor": "~2.0.0",
        "request": "^2.40.0",
        "sinon": "~1.10.3",
        "grunt-aws-s3": "^0.14.0",
        "grunt-contrib-compress": "^0.13.0",
        "grunt-git-rev-parse": "~0.1.4"
      };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with old version of grunt-express.